Gitlab: How to pass variable containing "$" special characters to another stage?
In Gitlab, need to pass a variable containing special character "$" to another stage via artifacts.
What I tried:
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - my_var='Admini$trator'
    - echo "pass=$my_var" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env 

test:
  stage: test
  needs:
    - job: build
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - echo $pass 

The output is "Admini" instead of "Admini$trator".
I also tried escaping with backslash "Admini\$trator" but I get "Admini\".
What is the correct way to escape artifact variables?
Later edit: Also tried pass=$${my_var} and echo 'pass=$my_var'

Have you tried using "pass=$${my_var}", it shouldn't expand the variable

In this case, this is not a Gitlab variable but rather "just" shell variable. Isn't it? Using simple quotes would avoid variable expansion echo 'pass=$my_var' for instance.

Does this answer your question? Escaping dollar sign and curly brace in bash

@GaëlJ & bhito I tried both your suggestion and I have the same issue

I found a solution. This might be the most dirty workaround I ever did:

surround "$" with backslashes: my_var='Admini\$\trator'
What it does: it escapes "$" in stage 1 and prevents the variable substitution in stage 2. In stage 2 the variable value will become: 'Admini$\trator'

replace "$\" with "$". I used python for this:
pass=$(python -c "s='$pass'.replace('\$\\\\', '\$'); print (s)")


Overall:
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - my_var='Admini\$\trator'
    - echo "pass=$my_var" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env 

test:
  stage: test
  needs:
    - job: build
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - pass=$(python -c "s='$pass'.replace('\$\\\\', '\$'); print (s)")
    - echo $pass # outputs Admini$trator correctly

If you have a string containing other special characters you can use this function inside stage 1:
    script:
        - |
          escape_special_characters() {
            local input="$1"
            local escaped_string
            local result
    
            escaped_string=$(printf '%q' "$input")
            result=$(python3 -c "s='$escaped_string'.replace('\\\\\$','\$\\\\'); print(s)") # Replace '\$' with '$\'
            
            echo "$result"
          }
        - echo escaped_pass=$(escape_special_characters "$pass") >> build.env 


The content of build.env is used to set shell environment variables. When build.env is parsed by GitLab in stage 2, variables are expanded by GitLab.
To keep the dollar sign, you need to escape the dollar sign (for GitLab) with the following in build.env.
pass=Admini$$trator

The achieve this you need to escape the dollar signs (for the shell) in the assignment in stage 1.
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - my_var=Admini\$\$trator
    - echo "pass=$my_var" >> build.env

Running this CI/CD pipeline gives the desired result.
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
$ echo $pass
Admini$trator

I am not sure why you use a normal environment variable for my_var and not a GitLab CI/CD variable.

Doesn`t work. it prints: "Admini" in stage 2

Hmmm, yes. It appears GitLab expands variables when parsing the dotenv file. I have updated my answer.
